# if decision with list variable

Tags: python, if-statement

In C/C++, true is standardized as 1, and false as 0. Although not a good practice,

```
if variable:  
    #do something
```

kind of decision making seems ok in python and it seems makes decision based on whether variable is None or is zero - if it is a number. Followings are reasonable.

```
a = 123123
if a:
    print "if condition is true"  # this prints

a = "a string"
if a:
    print "if condition is true"  # this prints

a = None
    if a:
        print "if condition is true"  # this does not print
```

However, I wonder why it evaluates to false with an empty list, which is neither None, nor zero. What is the exact implementation of python if statement?

```
a = [] # a is not  None
if a:
   print "true" # this does not print
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An if statement requires a bool. That means the the expression following the `if` is analyzed is a boolean context. Said differently it is converted to bool.

If a bool context, the following items evaluate to `False` (non exhaustive list):

- None
- numeric 0
- empty list
- empty string
- empty dict

Non null numerics and non empty iterables eveluate to `True`

Answer (score 0):

Lists are empty, so they're `False`, that's how python reacts, to know whether something is `False` so doesn't go trough, do:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>>
```

So it is `False`.